# What are these female 2.54mm (0.1") crimp terminals?

Tags: arduino, terminal, crimp

So I but some crimping terminals to make my own custom cable connections for the first time today for an Arduino project I'm currently working on.

Comparing to some older ones I have from premade jumper wires I had lying around, I found that they are definitely not the same shape, and I'm unsure they'll even be usable for my goals.

[image: Sample]

The terminals I'm used to seeing are in the center, the new ones I bought are on the left, and the sockets I have are like that one on the right.

I have tried fitting a new terminal into the socket, but as it was not crimped, It wouldn't fit, though the weird bent part did appear to go in, albeit relunctantly.

Are these usable with this kind of sockets? Did I screw up? Is there a common name for these types of crimp terminals so that I won't mess up while buying them in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You screwed up. There is no common name that I know of, at least not one used by a reputable manufacturer. The description you need is a crimp terminal that mates with 0.635mm/0.025" square post headers. The crimp terminal on the left clearly does not mate with a square post.

One example is the from Molex which is the "SL Series".

Comment: Thank you, I thought I screwed up, yeah. Welp.

Comment: I have come across these referred to generically as "DuPont connectors", at least when looking for cheap kits to make a few one-offs.

Comment: The one on the left looks like a Molex KK 0.1" .

Answer (score 0):

You must generally use contacts and housings from the same manufacturer and connector series.

Good distributors will usually specify what contacts are used with which housing.